# Replacing a for loop (that modifies an object) with a purrr function?

Tags: r, purrr, stringr

I'm working with a more complex version of this code, which includes a `for` loop.

At each step of the loop, the object `text` gets modified, based on two values in the `regex` data frame.

**Is there a way to replace that modifying `for` loop with a call to `purrr::walk2` or something like that?**

```r
library(tidyverse)

text <- "apple, orange, spinach"
regex <- tibble::tibble(
  find = c("[Aa]pples?", "[Oo]ranges?", "[Ss]pinach"),
  replace = c("fruit", "fruit", "vegetable")
)

# can this loop be replaced with purrr::walk2 or something like that?
for (i in 1:nrow(regex)) {
  text <- str_replace(text, regex$find[ i ], regex$replace[ i ])
}

# > text
# [1] "fruit, fruit, vegetable"
```

I have read this question: [How to replace a modifying for loop by purrr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57159153/how-to-replace-a-modifying-for-loop-by-purrr) -- but am unable to apply the solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach with `walk2`:

```
library(purrr)
walk2(.x = regex$find, .y = regex$replace,
      .f = ~assign("text", str_replace(text, .x, .y), envir = globalenv()))
text
#[1] "fruit, fruit, vegetable"
```

I agree with @MartinGal, however, that an alternative approach is probably a better plan.

Answer (score 1):

That's not what you asked for, but in this case I recommend

```r
unique(str_replace_all(text, regex$find, regex$replace))
```

which returns

```
[1] "fruit, fruit, vegetable"
```

Comment: (1) I tried that, but the problem is (and apologies for not saying so in the question) that I have multiple strings instead of `text`, and that some of those strings are of the form `"apple, orange"`. (2) Why `unique`?